# Alternative of ADF(AzureDataFactory) DataFlow

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

What can be an alternative of ADF Dataflow.

Data Flow is a new feature of Azure Data Factory (ADF) that allows users to develop graphical data transformation logic that can be executed as activities within ADF pipelines.

Is there any similar tool in AWS or GCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are similar tools to Azure Data Factory in both GCP and AWS, which provide a way to transform data at scale without any coding required. You can design a data transformation job in designer by constructing a series of transformations.

**Google Cloud Platform**:

- Google Cloud [Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion) - cloud-native data integration service that helps build and manage ETL/ELT data pipelines. With a graphical interface and a broad open-source library of preconfigured connectors and transformations, and more.

**Amazon Web Services**:

- AWS [Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) - focuses on data transfer. supports preload transformations using SQL commands. You can create a pipeline graphically through a console, using the AWS command line interface (CLI) with a pipeline definition file in JSON format, or programmatically through API calls.

Comment: I was looking for a similar toll like ADF Data Flow. not ADF

Comment: Please, take a look for edited answer. The tools are: Cloud Data Fusion and AWS Data pipeline. Hope it helps you.